# JS compare two multidimensional array and complete the second one with the dirrefences

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two multidimensional arrays:

```
const parent = [['ff@gmail.com', 'a@a.com', 'f@f.com'], ['ff@gmail.com']];
const customers = [['hh@gmail.com'], ['gg@gmail.com']];
```

**I would like to compare the parent[0] with customers[0] and parent[1] to customers[1] and if the customers is not contain the parent element push it to customer.**

what i try:

```
for(let x= 0; x < parent.length; x++){
 const innerArray = parent[x].length
  for(let y = 0; y < innerArray; y++){
        for (const customer of customers){
        if (!customer.includes(parent[x][y])){
        customer.push(parent[x][y])
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(customers)
```

the above code output is:

```
[["hh@gmail.com", "ff@gmail.com", "a@a.com", "f@f.com"], ["gg@gmail.com", "ff@gmail.com", "a@a.com", "f@f.com"]]
```

what i would like to output is :

```
[["hh@gmail.com", "ff@gmail.com", "a@a.com", "f@f.com"], ["gg@gmail.com", "ff@gmail.com"]]
```

Any help would appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just grab all strings from both the array and remove the duplicates using [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
const parent = [["ff@gmail.com", "a@a.com", "f@f.com"], ["ff@gmail.com"]];
const customers = [["hh@gmail.com"], ["gg@gmail.com"]];

const result = parent.map((arr, i) => {
  return [...new Set([...customers[i], ...arr])];
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const parentArr = [['ff@gmail.com', 'a@a.com', 'f@f.com'], ['ff@gmail.com']];
let customersArr = [['hh@gmail.com'], ['gg@gmail.com']];
let newCustomersArr = [];

customersArr.forEach((customer, i) => {
    if (!parentArr[i].includes(customer[0])) {
        newCustomersArr.push(customer.concat(parentArr[i]));
    }
})

console.log(newCustomersArr);
```